# r data.table Join In Place Multiple Columns

Tags: r, data.table

`data.table` is amazing.

I would like to do an in-place join but to keep all columns from both tables. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34598139/left-join-using-data-table/34600831) demonstrates how to do it for a single column. How do I generalize this when I want all of the columns from my joined table to be in the final result and have it all done in one memory location.

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                  col2 = 1:3, 
                  col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

setkey(dt1, col1)

set.seed(1)
dt2 <- data.table(col1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
                  another_col = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = TRUE), 
                  and_anouther = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 10, replace = TRUE))

setkey(dt2, col1)

# I want to stick the columns from dt1 onto dt2

# this works
dt3 <- dt2[dt1]
dt3
    col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
 1:    a           9        FALSE    1  TRUE
 2:    b           2        FALSE    2 FALSE
 3:    b           9        FALSE    2 FALSE
 4:    b           6        FALSE    2 FALSE
 5:    b           5         TRUE    2 FALSE
 6:    b           8        FALSE    2 FALSE
 7:    c           9         TRUE    3 FALSE
 8:    c           5        FALSE    3 FALSE
 9:    c           7        FALSE    3 FALSE
10:    c           6        FALSE    3 FALSE

# but i want to do this by reference

# this works for one column
dt2[dt1, col2 := i.col2]
dt2

    col1 another_col and_anouther col2
 1:    a           3        FALSE    1
 2:    a           8         TRUE    1
 3:    a           8         TRUE    1
 4:    b           2         TRUE    2
 5:    b           7        FALSE    2
 6:    b          10         TRUE    2
 7:    b           4        FALSE    2
 8:    c           4         TRUE    3
 9:    c           5         TRUE    3
10:    c           8         TRUE    3

# ok, remove that column
dt2[, col2 := NULL]

# now try to join multiple columns 
# this doesn't work
dt2[dt1, (col2 := i.col2, 
          col3 := i.col3)]

# neither does this
dt2[dt1, .(col2 := i.col2, 
          col3 := i.col3)]

# this just give me to the two columns
dt2[dt1, .(col2 = i.col2, 
           col3 = i.col3)]
dt2
   col2  col3
 1:    1  TRUE
 2:    1  TRUE
 3:    1  TRUE
 4:    2 FALSE
 5:    2 FALSE
 6:    2 FALSE
 7:    2 FALSE
 8:    3 FALSE
 9:    3 FALSE
10:    3 FALSE  

                ^
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Pretty much, I want the result from `dt3`, but I would like for it to created in place by reference as `dt2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should have looked at [one more questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913338/join-two-data-tables-and-use-only-one-column-from-second-dt-in-r?rq=1) which linked to this [awesome reference.](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html). All I needed to do was use the funcional form of the `:=` operator.

```
dt2[dt1, `:=` (col2 = i.col2, 
          col3 = i.col3)]

dt2
    col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
 1:    a           3        FALSE    1  TRUE
 2:    a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 3:    a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 4:    b           2         TRUE    2 FALSE
 5:    b           7        FALSE    2 FALSE
 6:    b          10         TRUE    2 FALSE
 7:    b           4        FALSE    2 FALSE
 8:    c           4         TRUE    3 FALSE
 9:    c           5         TRUE    3 FALSE
10:    c           8         TRUE    3 FALSE
```

Comment: The vignette is indeed good, but so is the help text, `?":="`, where `LHS := RHS ` form and Functional form are described.

Comment: Is there a way that works without having to type all the column names?

Comment: A method of merging all columns without typing them out is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043600/merging-all-column-by-reference-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 4):

The functional syntax is cleaner than the standard way.

```
dt2[dt1, c("col2", "col3") := .(col2, col3), on = c(col1 = "col1")][order(col1)]

    col1 another_col and_anouther col2  col3
 1:    a           3        FALSE    1  TRUE
 2:    a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 3:    a           8         TRUE    1  TRUE
 4:    b           2         TRUE    2 FALSE
 5:    b           7        FALSE    2 FALSE
 6:    b          10         TRUE    2 FALSE
 7:    b           4        FALSE    2 FALSE
 8:    c           4         TRUE    3 FALSE
 9:    c           5         TRUE    3 FALSE
10:    c           8         TRUE    3 FALSE
```